# MongoDB: Connecting to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB and I am successfully running it as a Windows Service, which I have called `MongoDB`. I am able to add data to the database through my ASP.NET MVC application, as expected. In the MongoDB configuration file, the path for my data is set to the default `C:\data\db`.

My question is: how can I now connect to this database from the command line? I want to be able to do things like delete the database or query it, and I want to do this from Windows command prompt. I am aware that running `mongo.exe` allows such functionality, but what arguments to I supply when I run it? I don't seem to ever recall giving a name to my database, other than naming the Windows Service...

Thanks :)

Comment: Just run mongo. Then `show dbs` to see the list of your databases. Then `use <dbsName>` and `show collections`. Then go to mongo documentation and read about queries.

Comment: Thanks. I see a database called `local`, which I assume is the default one set up. But when setting up my ASP.NET MVC project and MongoDB, what do I do if I want to call this database by a different name? And how do I specify which database my ASP.NET MVC application is actually using? Thanks!

Comment: I thought that in your question you wanted to know how to work from command line. Right now you are asking how to do thin in asp. You can not call this database by another name. You can create a new dbs with the name you want.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is designed to create databases on demand when you put data in them.  `local` is not a default; it holds internal state information like replication status.  You don't put your data there, and you definitely don't rename or delete it.  When interacting with a database using the mongo shell, you generally specify the db with `use dbname`; when using the C driver, you generally specify the dbname in calls to driver routines that return mongoc_database_t or mongoc_collection_t structs.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I love most about MongoDB is: you can almost find everything from [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/)
So there are two ways to specify database name:

```
mongo localhost/dbname
```

or you can connect to db first:

```
mongo // defaults to localhost/test
```

And then specify db name by

```
show dbs  // show all dbs
use dbName
```

You can almost do everything in mongo shell. Please read the [Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/).